# PostgreSQL connection issue after service restart

Tags: postgresql

I have edited my pg_hba file and copied it to server and restarted the services by "sudo service postgresql restart" but after that the server is not connecting.

Showing the below error, Your database returned: "Connection to 138.2xx.1xx.xx:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."

The Jenkins job and data visualization tools are failing which was working fine previously. What could be the reason.

Getting this in PostgreSQL Log

```
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11761] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11761] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-10-23 07:21:25.829 CEST [11766] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2019-10-23 07:21:25.832 CEST [11763] LOG:  shutting down
2019-10-23 07:21:25.919 CEST [11761] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-10-23 07:21:27.068 CEST [22633] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-23 07:21:25 CEST
2019-10-23 07:21:27.073 CEST [22633] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-10-23 07:21:27.075 CEST [22631] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-10-23 07:21:27.075 CEST [22637] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-10-23 07:21:27.390 CEST [22639] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Below shows no response.

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432
localhost:5432 - no response
```

Below was already added to the postgresql.config file.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Do i need to restart the entire server?

Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: First of all, try to restart postgresql service via: sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: @Madi7 Already done it multiple time. After conencting via SSH and type psql it is giving me this "Error: invalid line 616 in /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf: shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain’ # (change requires restart)"  , I have reboote dthe server via "sudo reboot" and restarted service again but it is not connecting.

Comment: @Madi7 Any help here please?

Comment: can you please paste the result of "service postgresql status" here

Comment: @Madi7 root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-10-23 08:34:14 CEST; 2min 40s ago
  Process: 1791 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1791 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 23 08:34:14 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Oct 23 08:34:14 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: @Madi7 It is active ,i have checked it.

Comment: Ok, so what are you getting, when typing: sudo -i -u postgres and then: psql ? Are you able to create and modify your databases ?

Comment: @Madi7 What is this command used for  sudo -i -u postgres ? WHen i try to connect via SSh and type "psql"i is showing Error: invalid line 616 in /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf: shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain’ # (change requires restart)

Comment: sudo -i -u postgres just moves you to the following dir: /var/lib/postgresql. Can you edit your postgresql.conf file ? Delete the line 616 and paste this: #shared_preload_libraries = '' And the try to restart via: service postgresql restart

Comment: @Madi7 I have done "sudo reboot"2-3 time and restarted postgresql service , it is not helping and connecting.

Comment: have you edited your file and then restarted ?

Comment: Ya, Editing this file and pasting like this ,#shared_preload_libraries = '', will update in few seconds.

Comment: @Madi7 i edited the config and when i type psql it is shwoing like this psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: ok thats something, now please do the following: either type sudo -i -u postgres or manually go the following dir: /var/lib/postgresql and then type: psql

Comment: @Madi7 same error                                                                                
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /var/lib/postgresql # psql
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: But now the data visualisation and Jenkins job is working, previously it was getting error.

Comment: But i have to ad the sharedpreload libraries right? Now i have commented it.

Comment: Lets continue this in chat, shall we ?

Comment: @Madi7 Sure ,Madi. So as of now i have disabled the loading of shared preload libraries, I need to enable that right? and if i enable will it cause any more error or Is there a way for tackle it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201304/discussion-between-madi7-and-sandeep).